# Entity 'changed' column doesn't change upon save

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity called "release". 
Release has "state" and "building percentage" fields, which values may change during the release process.

In both "setState" and "setPercentage" entity method I explicitly do the following:

```
$this->setChangedTime(time());
$this->save();
```

However, during the process, the "changed" column in the database always remains the same value. 
Am I missing something? What could be wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Running the "setState" and "setPercentage" in a test script separated, the database gets updated.

**UPDATE2:**

I got it. "ChangedItem.php" - line 37, I logged there, and this is where it sets back to the request time value:

```
   // On an existing entity translation, the changed timestamp will only be
      // set to the request time automatically if at least one other field value
      // of the entity has changed. This detection does not run on new entities
      // and will be turned off if the changed timestamp is set manually before
      // save, for example during migrations or by using
      // \Drupal\content_translation\ContentTranslationMetadataWrapperInterface::setChangedTime().
```

**will be turned off if the changed timestamp is set manually before save**

This "promise" of the comment is definitely not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you implementing `EntityChangedInterface` and also referencing `EntityChangedTrait` in your entity class (or extending from one that does so)?

Comment: Both, but good point!

Comment: Hmmm, so you're not overriding `setChangedTime` in your own class? That's odd, it should work in that case

Comment: The funny thing is: am now logging to watchdog, when "setState" and "setPercentage" was called:       \Drupal::logger('ifc_release')->info('Percentage time is: @time', array('@time' => $this->getChangedTime()));

In logging, it shows the right value. In phpmyadmin: it doesn't give a shit about it.

Answer (score 2):

Okey I found the final reason:

ChangedItem.php

```
  $original = $entity->original;
      $langcode = $entity->language()->getId();
      if (!$entity->isNew() && $original->hasTranslation($langcode)) {
        $original_value = $original->getTranslation($langcode)->get($this->getFieldDefinition()->getName())->value;
        if ($this->value == $original_value && $entity->hasTranslationChanges()) {
         $this->value = REQUEST_TIME;
        }
      }
```

**The conclusion:**

In Drupal 8 if you save the same entity TWICE within 1 second (for whatever reason), you won't able to save your own changed time BUT it will be the REQUEST_TIME instead... wtf? ...

Comment: It doesn't *ever* save your value, it always saves the request time. That's exactly what changed is for. If you don't want that, use a timestamp field type, not changed.

Comment: It saves your value, if the original entity "changed" value is different from the upcoming value HOWEVER if they are the same, the REQUEST TIME is going to be used, which can mean "the past" if it's a long process (like mine).

What I will have to do, to avoid the possibility that it jumps back to request time, that, if the original and new value is the same (before saving) I will increase with +1 second, and it will work.